# In python, get inconsistent returns when trying to reverse Pandas DataFrame values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to reverse values of DataFrame in Python as in the following codes. Strangely, x retuns what expected, but not y.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

x = pdr.DataReader('TQQQ', data_source='yahoo', start='2000-01-01')  
y = pdr.DataReader('^NDX', data_source='yahoo', start='2000-01-01') # ^NDX is a symbol for Nasdaq 100 Index

x[:] = x[::-1]
y[:] = y[::-1]

print(x)
print(y)
```

I suppose which symbol is called should not be a matter, but it seems to be matter.

Please help with it. Thank in advance for any comment and advice.

Comment: If you reorder the code to have x lines together and then the y lines together, does that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel there's inconsistency in the data downloaded. If you change all the columns as float type or string type, the 2 dataframes have the same behavior (doing nothing), as expected.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

x = pdr.DataReader('TQQQ', data_source='yahoo', start='2000-01-01')  
print(x)
for col in x.columns:
    x[col] = x[col].astype('float')
    #x[col] = x[col].astype('str')
x[:] = x[::-1]
print(x)

y = pdr.DataReader('^NDX', data_source='yahoo', start='2000-01-01') # ^NDX is a symbol for Nasdaq 100 Index
print(y)
for col in x.columns:
    y[col] = y[col].astype('float')
    #y[col] = y[col].astype('str')
y[:] = y[::-1]
print(y)
```

I have tried this line `df[:] = df[::-1]` on other dataframe, and it does **not** change anything.
However, this line `df = df[::-1]` will reverse the dataframe.

You should be using these lines instead:

```
x = x[::-1]
y = y[::-1]
```

Alternatively, you could use `sort_values()` to reverse the dataframe:

```
x = x.sort_values('Date', ascending=False)
y = y.sort_values('Date', ascending=False)
```

If you would like to reverse the dataframe without reversing the index, consider using

```
df = df.loc[::-1].set_index(df.index)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! The first solution reverse the index as well (i.e., reverse the whole DataFrame), but the second solution works perfectly. In my original posting, do you have any idea why x[:] = x[::-1] returns the same with your second solution, but y[:]=y[::-1] returns the same with your first solution?

Comment: I just realised that this line `df[:] = df[::-1]` is not supposed to do anything to the dataframe, you can try it on other dataframes. I've added more info to my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)  I am not clear why df[:] = df[::-1] does not change anything. Isn't that all values of df (i.e., df[:]) is changed to the reversed values of df (i.e., df[::-1])?

Comment: If you would like to reverse the dataframe without reversing the index, consider using `df = df.loc[::-1].set_index(df.index)`

Answer (score 1):

```
x[::-1] # reverses the data frame along with index i.e., date  
x[:]=x[::-1] # This replaces the data frame values but does not change index.
```

Therefore you can do this

```
x=x[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes, x[:] = x[::-1] reverses the values of DataFrame with keeping the index intact. However, in my original posting, y[:] = y[::-1] does not reverse anything while x[:] = x[::-1] works as expected. Do you have any idea why it happens?